# How to Restore Keychain from a Time Machine Backup?

Tags: time-machine

{Time-machine newbie} I would like to *replace* my Keychain Access with Keychain Access from a Time Machine backup.

I tried restoring the folder at ~Library/Keychain Access but what I ended up with was a folder called (Keychain Access Original) in the Library Directory. I've tried replacing files with the same name, but the restore has not been successful. How can I fix this?

I wouldn't mind doing a complete restore--that is, reverting to the Time Machine backup completely, if I knew how to do it...